# Postgres SQL recursive queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I am using PostgreSQL
there are two tables: Layers and Images

```
LAYERS (layer_id  varchar PRIMARY KEY,
        parent_id varchar REFERENCES LAYERS(layer_id))

IMAGES (image_id  varchar UNIQUE, REFERENCES LAYERS(layer_id))

in LAYERS table: 1->2->3->4->5->6 (1 is the parent of 2)
in IMAGES table: 1,2,5,6
```

Now I want to know, which image is the nearest parent image of image 5?
The answer is image 2

how to write such SQL query?
Thanks so much!

Comment: See the [Postgres tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+recursive-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE parents(id) AS(
   SELECT parent FROM layers WHERE layerid = '5'
   UNION
   SELECT layers.parent FROM parents, layers WHERE layers.layerid = parents.id
      AND parents.id NOT IN (SELECT imageid FROM images)
) 
SELECT imageid FROM parents, images WHERE images.imageid = parents.id;
```